# scroll down function on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

below is the code I have for scrollTop. It works fine when I target a specific pixel, but I want to scroll down 300px, instead of scrollTop a certain div on click. can anyone help?

```
<div id="button"></div>
<div1 style="height:300px;">img1</div>
<div2 style="height:300px;">img2</div>
<div3 style="height:300px;">img3</div>
<div4 style="height:300px;">img4</div>

$(function() {
$("#button").on("click", function() {
    $("html, body"). animate({"scrollTop":$().offset().top-300}, 1000);
    return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: `$()` does nothing, it has to be `{scrollTop:$(this).offset().top - 300}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$().offset().top` doesnt do much of anything. Replace it with `window.scrollY`

```
$(function() {
    $("#button").on("click", function() {
        $("body").animate({"scrollTop": window.scrollY-300}, 1000);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Also negative is up and positive is down when we're talking about scrolling so you probably want to add 300 instead.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `window.scrollBy(0,300);`

Comment: this doesnt animate tho

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the best way.

```
var body = $('html, body');
$('#button').click(function() {
   var n = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
   body.stop().animate({scrollTop: n }, 1000, function() {
});
});
```

Comment: Why is this the best way?

Comment: Because it scrolls down using actual height of your page minus window height. Not only the height of window.

Comment: Oh, I see, this topic is not about it xD